# Expanding softbody not colliding with cage object

Tags: collision, soft-body, force-fields

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IxcR_s3_VMs) to create an expanding balloon in a 3D frame.
However, with all the correct steps, the collision won't happen, even with the softbody solver step size set as 300.

Can anyone help out? Thanks in advance!
[file link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uAGg5QzsYnxTMfGKISnQpQD_r-JYqg0B/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

softbody:
[image]

force:
[image]

collision:
[image]

the whole view:
[image]

Comment: for every tutorial you are watching, it is *very* important to follow *each* step. You didn't apply the subdiv modifier as the tutorial said.

Comment: @Chris Thank you so much for the input! You're talking about the subdiv APPLY for the sphere, right? I must've missed it! I'll try it out later tonight!